# is covariance matrix and eigen vector question

Tags: covariance-matrix, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

is every covariance matrix 's eigenvector is orthogonal? 
why symmetric matrix's eigenvector is orthogonal?
can you show some example? and the reason?

$$\Sigma {\bf U_i} = \lambda_i U_i$$

additional question) why first eigenvalue is the direction of covariance matrix?
and second eigenvalue(what is second eigenvalue?) is the 90 degrees of the first eigenvalue?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal) on the math stackexchange site may help.

Answer (score 0):

Every covariance matrix is symmetric, that is, $\Sigma^T=\Sigma$. Then eigenvectors corresponding to **distinct eigenvalues** are orthogonal (you left out the important qualifier!). Here is a simple algebraic proof.

Let $\Sigma=\Sigma^T$ be symmetric, with eigenvectors $x, y$ such that
$$ \Sigma x=\lambda x, \Sigma y=\mu y, \quad \lambda \not=\mu, \lambda \not=0. $$
$x$ and $y$ are orthogonal means that $x^Ty=0$. Now
$$ x^Ty = \left( \frac1\lambda \Sigma x\right)^T y = \frac1\lambda x^T \Sigma y =\\
   \frac1\lambda \mu x^Ty $$
By subtraction we have
$$ x^Ty - \frac\mu\lambda x^T y =\left( 1-\frac\mu\lambda\right) x^T y=0
$$ and since $\lambda \not=\mu$ necessarily $x^Ty=0$.

That is the standard proof, and more details is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal

For your second question, what do you mean by direction of covariance matrix?

Comment: You don't need to assume $\lambda\ne 0,$ suggesting there's a simpler demonstration.   Indeed, the *symmetry* of $\Sigma$ implies $$\lambda y^\prime x = y^\prime (\Sigma x) = x^\prime\Sigma y = x^\prime \mu y = \mu y^\prime x.$$ Therefore $$(\lambda-\mu)\, y^\prime x = 0,$$ whence $\lambda=\mu$ or $y^\prime x = 0,$ *QED.* (I see now that this is exactly the approach taken in the answer you link to.)  More importantly, it's worth remarking that nonzero eigenvectors with the *same* eigenvalues are not necessarily orthogonal.